# Android FCM failed to post notification on channel "my_channel_01"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notification message from Firebase console to my app running on emulator.

The **MyFirebaseMessagingService** class looks like this:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "my_channel_01");
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("FCM Notification");
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationBuilder.setChannelId("my_channel_01");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

The constructor for NotificationCompat.Builder for API 26 now takes two params one is Context and another is String channelId. So I just assigned a random string to my channel.

But when I send the message from the firebase console the app on emulator gives me an error TOAST saying:

```
Failed to post notification on channel "my_channel_01"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe because of the image that you are using did not include the Play Store.

Comment: But I am getting the message in the logcat. Also my image is nexus 5s with Android 8.0 (Google APIs)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When your build specifies a `targetSdkVersion` of 26, and you run on an API level 26 device or emulator, you must both specify a channel ID when constructing [NotificationCompat.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html), and also create the channel.

You could use a method like this:

```
public static final String NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";

...

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void createNotifChannel(Context context) {
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID,
            "MyApp events", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
    // Configure the notification channel
    channel.setDescription("MyApp event controls");
    channel.setShowBadge(false);
    channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

    NotificationManager manager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

    manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    Log.d(TAG, "createNotifChannel: created=" + NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID);
}
```

And because it is only needed for API 26 and requires that level, invoke it like this:

```
// The channel need only be created for API 26 devices.  For devices
// running an API less the 26, there is no way to create a channel and the
// channel ID specified in the constuctor to NotificationCompat.Builder is
// merely a placeholder.
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    createNotifChannel(this);
}
```

It does no harm to recreate the [NotificationChannel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html), which provides some flexibility in where you do it.  If your app has multiple entry points (activity, broadcast receiver, etc) take care to ensure the channel is created for all cases.  You can also ensure it is only created once using [NotificationManager.getNotificationChannel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#getNotificationChannel(java.lang.String)):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    if (manager.getNotificationChannel(NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID) == null) {
        createNotifChannel(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: My min sdk level is 15 and targeted is 26. When I try to initialize the NotificationChannel constructor it gives me a lint error saying : call requires api level 26 (current min is 15)

Comment: Bracket the channel creation code in an if-statement with `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O` as I showed in the answer.  Or use the @RequiresApi annotation.

Comment: I have changed the code to the following: https://gist.github.com/neeraj87/97cf10d979005c4dfd13f16a8e26147a    but I am still uncertain as to how to handle notifications for api less than 26 as the new constructor for NotificationCompat.Builder takes channel as its second param

Comment: On devices with API level less that 26, the channel ID in the constructor is just a placeholder.  I don't think it is used.  Those API levels don't expect a channel with that ID to exist.  I think the code you posted should work, after you uncomment the notification generation.

Comment: Ok, can you please recheck the code and confirm if its alright? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you compiled it?  Looks okay, but I expected to see `import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;`

Comment: yes it compiled ok. I just copy pasted the lower part of the class so i missed putting the import. I will send a message from firebase consoe and see what happens

Comment: Bob, you are a god send human. this worked like a charm. I really appreciate your help. Thanks.