# Firebase notifications not showing up in my emulator

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying use Firebase to display a notification in an emulator.  The notification appears in the logcat view, but, the emulator displays a message "Failed to post Notification on Channel notify_001"
The referenced issue did not work for me.  I posted a new question so my exact code code be listed.
My SDK 
compileSdkVersion 26
minSdkVersion 18
targetSdkVersion 26

Code:

```
public class MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyAndroidFCMService";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //Log data to Log Cat
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        Log.i(TAG, "instance id " + FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId());
        //create notification
        createNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    private void createNotification( String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( this , ResultActivity. class );
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this , 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri notificationSoundURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder
                ( this, "Notify_001")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Android Tutorial Point FCM Tutorial")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel( true )
                .setSound(notificationSoundURI)
                .setContentIntent(resultIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("notify_001",
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android FCM failed to post notification on channel "my\_channel\_01"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341603/android-fcm-failed-to-post-notification-on-channel-my-channel-01)

Comment: The answer(s) given on the referenced issue, did not solve the problem for me.  Do I need to add a comment and post my code to the other question/issue?  My guess is there is something else in my code that is incorrect.

Comment: I did attempt to add a comment to the referenced questions, but I don't have a high enough reputation to do so, so, I could not post my code to inquire as to where I went wrong.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi jbg2408. Have you tried creating the notification channel from the Application class itself first (AFAIK, this is how it should be done) -- that way, you won't have to actually call the `createNotificationChannel` every time you create a notification. I had a sample made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46946289/4625829) if it helps.

Comment: Thank you. That solved the issue.  I still  have things I need to learn about the process but, having a working example helps.
Thanks again....