# FCM notifications not working in Android latest version OREO

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM notifications are not working in Android latest version OREO.

Below is my code:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/luncher_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/luncher_logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="com.example.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />


        <service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".firebase.FirebaseIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? Are you sending FCM notification or FCM data? 
Documentation -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: show your `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class ..

Comment: Please refer latest documentation of Notification from developers. It might be the case that you are missing Channel id.

Comment: Please read: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/. At minimum, we'd need to see what you expected, and what you actually got, including error messages and stack traces. Additionally, please avoid txtspk here, as you will find it will irritate some readers; pleasantries are not really necessary, but if you must add "please", there really is no need to abbreviate it.

Answer (score 5):

In Android Oreo making channel is important,When yo create notification you must pass the channel id,or your notification won't show up in Oreo devices.

[more information](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)

quick fix is:
use setChannelId method in notification class.

```
 Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif_icon)
  .setContentTitle("testTitle")
  .setContentText(messageBody)
  .setAutoCancel(true)
  .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
  .setChannelId("testChannelId") // set channel id
  .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

complete answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341603/android-fcm-failed-to-post-notification-on-channel-my-channel-01).

Answer (score 4):

From Android 8.0 (API level 26+), notification channels are supported and recommended.

> FCM provides a default notification channel with basic settings.

If you prefer to create and use your own default channel, set `default_notification_channel_id` to the ID of your notification channel object as shown below.

> FCM will use this value whenever incoming messages do not explicitly set a notification channel.

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
```

You can create channel id from this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateChannel)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create channels in order to display a notification in `Oreo`.

If you use default firebase notifications, you can add `channel_id` in manifest.

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
   android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
```

If you create notifications manually, then you need to create channel programmatically. More details on [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client).